# How many inserts can be done within one transaction in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I'm trying to insert a large amount of records (in the millions) into an SQLite database. The data is read in from a file stream (C++). If I begin a single transaction, perform *all* of the inserts and then commit the transaction, I only get a very small percentage of records actually inserted in my database.

The ones that are inserted seem random -- I can't really see any pattern for which ones do get inserted and which ones get left out. However, if I commit and then begin the transaction again after something like 2000 inserts, I don't have this problem and all of the records are inserted, even though the process is *much* slower. So...

Is there a strict limit to how many inserts can be done within one transaction? Is there a way to change this limit?

Comment: Got into this issue as well. Just gonna post this here for posterity. If you encounter this, should first try to batch only 1k-2k inserts per transaction to see if this is indeed the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, you need seperate 100 items for each transaction.

Answer (score 20):

I am able to insert 10 millions rows in a single transaction without a problem.

My guesses:

- you are inserting too much rows in a single statement and hitting Maximum Depth Of An Expression Tree limit. This can be switched off completely.
- you are using overly long INSERTs without binding values and hitting Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement limit. In this case, use parameter binding.
- it may be a bug in the library (are you checking every API return for error codes?)

Check [Limits In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). It may help if you show how you prepare and execute INSERTs in the code.