# sqlite3: multiple updates in one transaction

Tags: python, sqlite

I've learned how to put multiple INSERTs into one transaction using SELECT UNION as in this example

```
var newQuery = true, query = '';
for (i=0; i<locations_length; i++) {
    if (newQuery) {
        query = 'INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, code)';
        newQuery = false;
    }
    else {
        query += ' UNION';
    }

    query += ' SELECT "'+values[i][0]+'", "'+values[i][1]+'", "'+values[i][2]+'"';

    if (i!=0 && i%499==0) {
        db.execute(query);
        newQuery = true;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for multiple UPDATEs.

Is there any way I can put multiple UPDATEs into one transaction?

Also, is there a way to put mixture of INSERTs and UPDATEs into one transaction?

I'm working with Python 2.7 by the way.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You are working in Python, yet you posted non Python code. Are you referencing non-Python code and trying to reproduce it in Python?

Comment: Looks like javascript...  How dare you call javascript python?

Comment: You can't mix INSERT and UNIONs http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` and you can make any number of statements occur in a single transaction.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: thank you very much. Does it really have no limit? I'm speaking a few hundred million INSERTs and UPDATEs

Comment: The limits are probably dependent on your system and sqlite configuration. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199305/sqlite-number-of-transactions-limit

Comment: Thanx! Btw, Will it work for UPDATEs as well? And the mixture of UPDATEs and INSERTs?

Comment: Yes. My understanding is that *any* type of database modifications can be made into a single transaction this way.