# Limit for executemany statement of sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

What is the maximum limit on number of tuples that can be inserted through `executemany` statement of sqlite3 in python?

Comment: Have you seen e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7199305/3001761?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite itself has no practical limit, i.e., you can insert as much data as fits on the disk. (Unless you have a disk larger than [140 TB](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).)

Therefore, the only remaining limit is the second parameter of `executemany`, i.e., the sequence of tuples.
If you use an iterator instead of a static sequence, this can be arbitrarily large.